# Creating an on-the-spot ActiveRecord::Relation substitute

Tags: ruby, activerecord, arel

We have a situation where we find ourselves in need to use ActiveRecord facilities to query tables, but we do not want to create long-lived or "global" classes for those tables. For example, we really need to do things like

```rb
from_table(table_name).find_in_batches do |row|
   ...
```

So far what I've come up with is this:

```rb
def temporary_model_class_for_table(table_name)
  Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) do
    self.table_name = table_name
  end
end
```

which allows us to do the following:

```rb
temporary_model_class_for_table('widgets').where(id: 1)
```

which returns an instance of the anonymous class that `temporary_model_class_for_table` returns. But I wonder whether there might be a cleaner way to do this. Maybe using something like Github's SQL gem or accessing resultsets directly? On the other hand, things like `find_in_batches` / `find_each` are ActiveRecord parts, not Arel parts and thus likely require the full (vast) ActiveRecord API to be present.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: What is the benefit of having `from_table(table_name).find_in_batches` instead of `TableName.find_in_batches` with a simple `class TableName < ApplicationRecord; end`?

Comment: Fair question - the point is that we need to work with tables which result from online schema changes (they are "old" tables which have gotten replaced in-place by new ones)

Comment: If true models are not necessary then you can use Arel and `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` i.e. `table = Arel::Table.new('widgets'); ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(table.project(table[Arel.star]).where(table[:id].eq(1)).to_sql).each {|row|}`. Here each `row` will be yielded to the block as a `Hash` where the structure is `{'column' => 'value'}`

Comment: If you want to avoid all the rails overhead caused by AR I would recommend the `sequel` gem. It offers a comprehensive and intuitive DSL without all the bells and whistles of AR's syntactic sugar